# SoftLayer API : How to get list VM created from baremetal

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to get a list of VMs provisioned from baremetal servers rather than from Xen servers.

The following api lists me VMs from Xen server and not from Baremetal,
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried that and I am not sure if that is possible, but I think you may see this methods:

Your bare metal server should have a virtual host you can get that virtual host using this:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getVirtualHost

If you do not get any virtual host you can try import it using this:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/importVirtualHost

If you can get the virtual host you can use these method to manage the guests:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Host

and this one is for list the guests
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Host/getGuests

Regards